# Editing column format when JSON is not valid

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

New to SharePoint so I hope I'm not doing anything silly, but I tried to edit a column format using JSON. It was working, and then I added an addition IF statement.

I messed it up and now it only shows this error:

[image]

Anytime I add that column back into the view, it throws this error. How do I edit the column to fix the mistake without being able to see the column itself?

Every google search only shows editing it by left clicking on the column itself.

Comment: Could you please post the JSON you're using?

Comment: Hi, does my below answer help you in any way? Let me know if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the JSON you applied from column settings. follow below steps for same:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on settings (gear) icon from top right corner and select **List settings**
3. From list settings page, scroll down to **Columns** section and click on column name where you have applied JSON formatting

   [image]
4. From column settings page, scroll down to **Column Formatting** section. Copy everything inside the text box below this section, paste it in your local file to keep it as backup.
5. Then remove all the content inside the text box and click **OK** to save changes.

This should fix your issue. Then you can change/fix your backup JSON in your favorite code editor (I prefer Visual Studio Code) and apply it to column formatting again.